# Why do I get NoResultException in hibernate when there is a data in the database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I trying to get an entity from the MySql database in hibernate using HQL by email. However, I get `javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query` even though it exists in the database. I am trying to retrieve it by email using getSingleResults() and the emails are unique in the database so I am sure that there is only going to be a single result.

Please refer the code below:

```
@Override
    public UserDetails getUser(String email) {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query query = currentSession.createQuery("from UserDetails u where u.email = :email ");
        query.setParameter("email", email);
        return (UserDetails) query.getSingleResult();
    }
```

Please refer the following code for the entity class:

```
package com.travelplanner.rest.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users_details")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Transient
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<TravelPlans> travelPlans;

    public UserDetails() {
    }

    public UserDetails(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<TravelPlans> getTravelPlans() {
        return travelPlans;
    }

    public void setTravelPlans(List<TravelPlans> travelPlans) {
        this.travelPlans = travelPlans;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

    public void add(TravelPlans travelPlan) {
        if (travelPlans == null) {
            travelPlans = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        travelPlans.add(travelPlan);

        travelPlan.setUserDetails(this);
    }

}
```

The code in controller if it helps:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{email}")
    public UserDetails authUser(@PathVariable String email) {
        return userService.getUser(email);
    }
```

The request url is: http://localhost:8080/api/users/xlz@wwe.com

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Time to debug ...

Comment: Okay I tried it locally, and Spring auto-decodes the @ character for you, so can you please provide some more information? what data the getUser function gets? is it correct, or null? How does your entity looks like? Can you select all without the email parameter of it?

Comment: Is the email column case sensitive?

Comment: @aBnormaLz The getUser() should return only a single entity of UserDetails.

Comment: Okay, but i'm not sure what is the problem. So if you can get it without the email parameter, then the problem is with your email parameter. If you cannot get it without the parameter, then the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I have added the entity class.

Comment: @aBnormaLz The problem why do I get NoResultException when xlz@wwe.com exists in the database.

Comment: Does it really exists in your database? Aren't you set the parameter for example to XLZ@WWE.COM instead? Please try it without the filter, and use getResultList to see what happens then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define the name of the path variable. 
Please replace  `@PathVariable String email` to `@PathVariable(value="email") String email` 
.

According to the above comment You have to encode email in request `xlz%40wwe.com`
but it is not necessary to decode it in java code. It should work without decoding.

Comment: Tried @PathVariable(value="email") String email , still I get the exception.

Comment: Ni, I did not. Could you please demonstrate how it could be done.

Comment: add `System.out.println(email);` into getUser() method at the first row of the method! and look which email is requested.

Comment: That was very helpful! It appears that the .com is missing. It's just xlz@wwe Why is it cutting it out?

Comment: Thanks I have implemented the solution and the response is now 406.